# Rspec request spec fails in anyway. How to test ActiveStorage attach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I think it should be quite easy but I struggle.
I use an API only Rails 6.1.x app ( with `ActionController::Base` )

```
User has_one :shop has_one_attached :company_logo
```

That action works when I do a real upload from the frontend. But the spec is not working

```rb
  def update_company_logo
    if params[:company_logo].present?
      image = params[:company_logo]
      if image && @current_user.shop.company_logo.attach(image)
        render json: @current_user, status: :ok
    end
  end
```

This is my spec and all my approaches providing the file:

```rb
      fixture_logo = file_fixture('400x400.png')


      let(:company_logo_fixture) { file_fixture('400x400.png') } 
      # ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

      let(:company_logo_upload) { fixture_file_upload(file_fixture('400x400.png'), 'image/png') } 
      # ArgumentError: Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActionController::Parameters {"original_filename"=>"400x400.png", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007fb427c65240>", "content_type"=>"image/png"} permitted: false>

      let(:company_logo_request) { ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(tempfile: fixture_logo, filename: File.basename(fixture_logo), type: 'image/png') }
      # ArgumentError: Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActionController::Parameters {"tempfile"=>"spec/fixtures/files/400x400.png", "original_filename"=>"400x400.png", "content_type"=>"image/png", "headers"=>nil} permitted: false>

      let(:company_logo_blob) { blob_for("400x400.png") } 
      # ArgumentError: Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1, "key"=>"veeg1kjbeiuezvzb671get9yfgwp", "filename"=>"400x400.png", "content_type"=>"image/png", "metadata"=>{"identified"=>true}, "service_name"=>"test", "byte_size"=>1307, "checksum"=>"1MOyYUXElEWrikZgxC5PJA==", "created_at"=>"2021-09-27T09:01:55.177Z", "attachable_sgid"=>"BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSI1Z2lkOi8vbWV0YS1zaG9wL0FjdGl2ZVN0b3JhZ2U6OkJsb2IvMT9leHBpcmVzX2luBjsAVEkiDHB1cnBvc2UGOwBUSSIPYXR0YWNoYWJsZQY7AFRJIg9leHBpcmVzX2F0BjsAVDA=--732a4fdc460b203766c226b28e81bf1f75af7d45"} permitted: false>

      let(:company_logo_rack) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(file_fixture('400x400.png'), "image/png") } 
      # ArgumentError: Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActionController::Parameters {"original_filename"=>"400x400.png", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x00007fd0312cd360>", "content_type"=>"image/png"} permitted: false>

      let(:image_double) { instance_double(Rack::Test::UploadedFile, content_type: 'image/png', original_filename: '400x400.png', file_name: file_fixture('400x400.png')) }

      it "attaches the company_logo" do
        file = file_fixture('400x400.png')

        post company_logo_shops_url,
             params: { company_logo: image_double },
             headers: valid_headers(shop.user),
             as: :json
        expect(shop.company_logo).to be_attached
      end
```

What I found out was, that the "company_logo" upload from the real frontend" has an "ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile" format,

While the rSepc "upload" was mostly "HashWithIndifferentAccess". Could this be the problem? And how to solve?

Comment: What storage method is ActiveStorage using in your test environment? Could it be misconfigured?

Comment: in `environments/test.rb`: `config.active_storage.service = :test` , `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: ENV.fetch("PORT") }`, `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['APPLICATION_URL'] }` . But you suggest, that one of these should be working?

Comment: Might be worth trying `config.active_storage.service = :local_test` but RSpec isn't really my thing I'm afraid. The object *types* you receive are different in test, but are the object *contents* the same? Clearly, something about your test setup isn't duplicating the normal environment.

Comment: Was this solved? what was the solution?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, and the posted answer doesn't fix it.
Did you find an answer @Jan  ??

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue when trying to test my image upload request spec.

The only way I could get this one to work was by using the following to prepare my file payload:

```rb
let(:file) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/images/test.jpeg'), 'image/jpg') }

let(:params) {{ image: file }}

----

it 'returns a 201' do
  post(endpoint, headers:, params:)

  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
end

it 'attaches the image' do
  post(endpoint, headers:, params:)

  expect(company.image).to be_attached
end
```

Comment: that worked for me too, but I recommend to delete the files after the tests

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#discarding-files-created-during-tests